# How to run cmd command using Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, scripting, jboss

Requirement - I want to trigger command "service.bat install" from CMD as administrator in Python Script.
I am using below code as of now and it is opening a new windows for asking permission to say yes.

```
source_path = 'C:\\JBoss_Playground\\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\\bin\\service'
cmd_command = 'service.bat install'
os.chdir(source_path)
subprocess.call(cmd_command, shell=True)
```

Now, I want to run the above command in background using admin privileges on Windows server. This is to a module to automate JBoss/Wildfly application service configuration.

Appreciate for your help.
Thank You !!

Comment: check this out [run as admin] (https://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/216230-how-change-admin-mode-cmd.html) 
You run this command first and then all the other.
*Notice:Your quetion must be which is the command  to change user to admin.

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
os.system('your command')
```

To start it as admin I think that python script have to be executed as root. For background process...
In my project I used:

````
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate('dir c:\\')
stdout```

I tryed in python idle and it returns:
'Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]...'
````

Comment: The above code seems to be fine, below is my python code as of now-
    path = 'C:\\JBoss_Playground\\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\\bin\\service'      
    os.chdir(path)
    proc = subprocess.Popen('service.bat install', shell=True, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = proc.communicate(proc)
    print(out)

Now, the problem is that this code execution is still asking me about Windows Permission to say "Yes" to run the command "service.bat install" as that needs to be run using CMD as administrator. 

Kindly suggest.............!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `runas` command? You can change to admin mode. Please check this [runas syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html)